# Hide floating action button child in another fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I implemented a `Floating Action Button` for open another two if it's pressed in one `Fragment`. But, in the app I have 2 fragments. So if I slide over another interface, and left it open in the first one, it will keep appearing only the two "fab child", while the `Floating Action Button` "parent" fades, how should be. How can I fix this?

Fab:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabShow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"
    android:tint="@color/colorTextFloatingBtn"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorBackgroundAccept"
    android:scaleType="center"
    app:fabSize="mini" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabShow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"
    android:tint="@color/colorTextFloatingBtn"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorBackgroundAccept"
    android:scaleType="center"
    app:fabSize="mini" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    android:tint="@color/colorTextFloatingBtn"
    android:scaleType="center"

    app:fabSize="mini" />
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fab.hide();
            fabShow1.hide();
            fabShow2.hide();
            break;
        case 1:
            fab.show();
            break;
        default:
            fab.hide();
            fabShow1.hide();
            fabShow2.hide();
            break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such method as `view.hide()`. You should set the visibility to the views instead.

Try like below

```
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fabShow1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fabShow2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 1:
        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    default:
        fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fabShow1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fabShow2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
 }
```

Comment: Well, I tried as suggested me. But now all the fab's shows up in case 0, when it's open.

Comment: You should try to handle the same in `onCreateView` of your first fragment.